# Display none does not work on Microsoft Outlook App

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am sending emails from the server to the customers and my html code works perfectly on every platform except Microsoft Outlook Desktop.

I am using html email templates with keys inside that I replace according to customers and email properties such as:

```
<tr style="display: {{displayProduct}};">
```

It turns into:

```
<tr style="display: none;">
```

There are product info under this  such as productName. It does not display on other email clients but in outlook it looks like this:

[image]

I have used mso-hide attribute but it does not work. I placed it next to where display none is used. If display is none, also mso-hide:all. But it does not work.

I looked to the solutions in [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974445/outlook-web-app-display-none-not-working), but none of them worked.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mso-hide:all;` on the `<td>`(s) rather than the `<tr>`. Outlook for Windows is very specific about what can go where, and it's not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. Word considers the `display` cascading style sheet property as unsupported and unknown.

You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.